# need flexbox children to display normally

Tags: css, flexbox, children

How to make flexbox children behave like the bad children they are.  This means their default layout.

```
.wrapper {
  this is the row
}
.column {
  all equal heights
  display:flex;
}
.child {
  back to normal display....uneven heights and widths.  Currently it seems like the children want to display as flex (equal heights) also.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted no HTML markup I'm going to assume the structure you have is similar to this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div><!-- /.wrapper -->
```

In your example, it makes sense that the `.child` elements are displaying as flex items, because their parent, in this case `.column`, is set to display `flex`. What you are probably after is setting the `.wrapper` to display flex, so the `.column` is the flex child.

Something like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/rd2npn4v/

The first example in the fiddle is what you have, and the second is setting the `.wrapper` to display flex.

Hopefully this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @AdrianRoth I'm not sure what you mean, look at this updated fiddle for the second example (I only changed the color of one of the columns in the second example). The columns are full height, but the children height are determined by content. https://jsfiddle.net/disinfor/rd2npn4v/4/

Comment: Reposting because stacks rules are silly... and this comment box likes to submit when I hit some magical combination of keys when I'm typing a million miles per hour.

Comment: Sorry, should have posted the html too.  That's the right code.

I tried it both ways.  Setting the wrapper as flex did nothing.  Setting the columns as flex fixed the height of the columns but then messed up the children.

It seems that there is a magical combination of css settings that need correct for this to work but that's not documented.

Does anything need to be floated or will floating make this not work.

Position? Display? Heights? Widths?  I'm trying to think of other things that commonly effect layout if not set correctly........

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please reread my comments.  I tried editing but it didn't work.

Comment: You don't need floats for flex-box display. Flex-box is effectively in place of floats.

If my updated fiddle isn't what you're looking for perhaps you can post an image of what you're looking to do. You also might have some other css that is affecting your elements.

Comment: What you have looks right.  Unfortunately I did a work around using jquery and had to turn it over to the client so it would be hard for me to get you a screen shot.

One of my children had a whole other set of divs (row and columns) with h2s, ps, etc.....and while the top cols were equal heights it put the sub set of divs, h2, p all in 1 row.  Basically prevented lines from breaking.  This was when I applied flex to the cols.  When I applied flex to the wrapper, like you suggest, nothing happened.

Let me stew on this....I'll see if there's away I can get you a screen shot of the problem.

Comment: Editing your original question with your HTML structure would be very helpful.